# Global runtime configuration variable in NextJS (server side)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using `instrumentation.ts` file of NextJS to dynamically fetch configuration on the startup of the server and would like to make this configuration available during runtime to all api routes and server side components. What is the best approach to make this object available?

I am considering Node `global` variable, but it doesn't feel like the best practice. What should be the cleanest approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a ConfigProvider class that i am initialising in the instrumentation for nodejs runtime only (edge doesn't support some functionality, but i don't need my config in middleware luckily):

I created a GlobalRef class first:

```
export interface KeyableObject { [key: string]: string | number | boolean | KeyableObject | KeyableObject[] | string[] | boolean[] | number[] }

class GlobalRef<KeyableObject> {
    private readonly sym: symbol;

    constructor(uniqueName: string) {
        this.sym = Symbol.for(uniqueName);
    }

    get value() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        return (global as any)[this.sym] as KeyableObject;
    }

    set value(value: KeyableObject) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        (global as any)[this.sym] = value;
    }
}
```

and used it in my ConfigPrivder to store the reference to my config:

```
class MyConfigProvider {
    

    init = async () => {
        const configBuilderInst = new GlobalRef('configBuilderPromise');
        if (!configBuilderInst.value) {
            configBuilderInst.value = this.build_config_instance();
        }
        await configBuilderInst.value
    }

    resolve = async (key: string) => {
        const config = await this.get_config() as KeyableObject;
        return config[key] ?? null;
    }

    private get_config = () => {
        const configBuilderInst = new GlobalRef('configBuilderPromise');
        if (!configBuilderInst.value) {
            configBuilderInst.value = this.build_config_instance();
        }
        return configBuilderInst.value
    }

    private build_config_instance = async () => {
        let config_instance: KeyableObject = {}

        //... CODE TO FETCH MY CONFIG FROM STORAGE etc.

        return config_instance
    }
}
const ConfigProvider = new MyConfigProvider();
export default ConfigProvider;
```

Finally in my instrumentation.ts:

```
export async function register() {
    if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME == "nodejs") {
        try {
            const ConfigProvider = (await import("configLoader")).default;
            await ConfigProvider.init();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("Unable to init config provider")
        }
    }
}
```

I am then able to retrieve it anywhere in my app:

```
const configVar = await ConfigProvider.resolve("MY_CONFIG_VAR") as string;
```

Answer (score -2):

Using a Node.js global variable to store configuration data may not be the cleanest or safest approach, as it can lead to various issues, such as unintentional modification of the global state and potential security risks. Instead, you can consider more structured and safer approaches to make configuration data available to all API routes and server-side components in Next.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).